# UISegmentedControl not intractable when there is nothing above it

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiscrollview, uikit, uisegmentedcontrol

My issue is so specific that I have to give the code for this, sorry if the code is too convoluted or complicated, I am a bit new to UIKit since I have been learning SwiftUI more instead of UIKit.

I have a really complicated `UITableView` header with some nice animations and such, and I put a `UISegmentedControl` on top. However, as soon as a `UITableViewCell` gets behind the `UISegmentedControl`, it stops working and user interaction capabilities are lost with the `UISegmentedControl`.

This is too hard to explain without visual context and code, so here it is.

As you can see, at the top, the user can interact with the UISegmentedControl freely, but when I start scrolling and table view cells are going behind the `UISegmentedControl` (as expected), the segmented control stops responding to user touch input completely.

[image: 1]

Again, excuse me for the long (and probably bad) code, I am still learning.

This is the code for the UITableView that I wrote:

```swift
class TertiaryProfileScroll: UITableViewController {
    var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!
    
    var testBlurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    var headerTitle: UIStackView!
    var blurView: UIVisualEffectView!
    var scoreRect: UIView!
    var scoreLabel: UILabel!
    
    var originalBlurRect: CGRect!
    var originalTitleRect: CGRect!
    var originalTestRect: CGRect!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        let headerView = SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: view.bounds.width, height: 488))
        
        let image = UIImage(named: "background_image")
        
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize(width: 350, height: 350), false, 4)
        image!.draw(in: CGRect(origin: CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), size: CGSize(width: 350, height: 350)))
        let newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        
        tableView.allowsSelection = false
        tableView.separatorStyle = .none
        
        headerView.imageView.image = newImage
        
        tableView.tableHeaderView = headerView
        addTitle()
        
        blurView.contentView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        
        tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    }
    
    override func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        guard tableView.tableHeaderView != nil else { return }
        
        let headerView = self.tableView.tableHeaderView as! SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView
        let headerGeometry = self.geometry(view: headerView, scrollView: scrollView)
        
        let titleGeometry = self.geometry(view: headerTitle, scrollView: scrollView)
        
        (tableView.tableHeaderView as! SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView).containerView
            .alpha = CGFloat(sqrt(headerGeometry.largeTitleWeight))
        (tableView.tableHeaderView as! SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView).imageContainer.alpha = CGFloat(sqrt(headerGeometry.largeTitleWeight))
        
        let largeTitleOpacity = (max(titleGeometry.largeTitleWeight, 0.5) - 0.5) * 2
        let tinyTitleOpacity = 1 - min(titleGeometry.largeTitleWeight, 0.5) * 2
        
        headerTitle.alpha = CGFloat(sqrt(largeTitleOpacity))
        
        blurView.contentView.subviews[1].alpha = CGFloat(sqrt(tinyTitleOpacity))
        
        if let vfxSubview = blurView.subviews.first(where: {
            String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UIVisualEffectSubview"
        }) {
            vfxSubview.backgroundColor = UIColor.systemBackground.withAlphaComponent(0)
        }
        
        if let vfxBackdrop = blurView.subviews.first(where: {
            String(describing: type(of: $0)) == "_UIVisualEffectBackdropView"
        }) {
            vfxBackdrop.alpha = CGFloat(1 - sqrt(titleGeometry.largeTitleWeight))
        }
        
        var blurFrame = blurView.frame
        var titleFrame = headerTitle.frame
        
        blurFrame.origin.y = max(originalBlurRect.minY, originalBlurRect.minY + titleGeometry.blurOffset)
        titleFrame.origin.y = originalTitleRect.minY + 364
        
        blurView.frame = blurFrame
        headerTitle.frame = titleFrame
        
        headerView.scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: scrollView)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        1000
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
        
        cell?.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)
        
        cell?.layer.zPosition = -1000
        
        view.sendSubviewToBack(cell!)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(tableView.tableHeaderView!)
        
        return cell!
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
    }
    
    func addTitle() {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .dark : .light)
        blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 44 + 38 + tableView.safeAreaInsets.top)
        
        segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: secondaryProfilePages)
        segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
        
        segmentedControl.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 32, height: 30)
        
        let scoreSize = ("+\(String(9999))" as NSString).boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.truncatesLastVisibleLine, .usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)], context: nil).size
        scoreLabel = PaddingLabel(withInsets: 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5)
        scoreLabel.text = "+\(String(9999))"
        scoreLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        scoreLabel.textColor = .black
        scoreLabel.backgroundColor = .white
        scoreLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        scoreLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        
        let smallScoreLabel = PaddingLabel(withInsets: 2.5, 2.5, 5, 5)
        smallScoreLabel.text = "+\(String(9999))"
        smallScoreLabel.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .caption1)
        smallScoreLabel.textColor = .label
        smallScoreLabel.backgroundColor = UITraitCollection.current.userInterfaceStyle == .dark ? .white : .black
        smallScoreLabel.layer.masksToBounds = true
        smallScoreLabel.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        
        let nsText = "OmerFlame" as NSString?
        
        let bigLabelSize = nsText?.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 32 - scoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.truncatesLastVisibleLine, .usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 34, weight: .black)], context: nil).size
        
        let smallLabelSize = nsText?.boundingRect(with: CGSize(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 32 - scoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude), options: [.truncatesLastVisibleLine, .usesLineFragmentOrigin], attributes: [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)], context: nil).size
        
        let largeLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: bigLabelSize!.width, height: bigLabelSize!.height))
        let smallLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: smallLabelSize!.width, height: smallLabelSize!.height))
        
        largeLabel.text = "OmerFlame"
        largeLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 34, weight: .black)
        largeLabel.textColor = .white
        largeLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        largeLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.2
        largeLabel.allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = true
        largeLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        
        smallLabel.text = "OmerFlame"
        smallLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 18, weight: .bold)
        smallLabel.textColor = .label
        smallLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
        smallLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0.1
        smallLabel.allowsDefaultTighteningForTruncation = true
        smallLabel.numberOfLines = 1
        
        largeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        smallLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        headerTitle = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: largeLabel.frame.size.width + 5 + scoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: max(largeLabel.frame.size.height, scoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height)))
        
        headerTitle.axis = .horizontal
        headerTitle.alignment = .center
        headerTitle.distribution = .equalCentering
        
        headerTitle.addArrangedSubview(largeLabel)
        headerTitle.addArrangedSubview(scoreLabel)
        
        let smallHeaderTitle = UIStackView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: smallLabel.frame.size.width + 5 + smallScoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width, height: max(smallLabel.frame.size.height, smallScoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height)))
        
        smallHeaderTitle.axis = .horizontal
        smallHeaderTitle.alignment = .center
        smallHeaderTitle.distribution = .equalCentering
        
        smallHeaderTitle.addArrangedSubview(smallLabel)
        smallHeaderTitle.addArrangedSubview(smallScoreLabel)
        
        blurView.contentView.addSubview(headerTitle)
        blurView.contentView.addSubview(smallHeaderTitle)
        blurView.contentView.addSubview(segmentedControl)
        tableView.tableHeaderView!.addSubview(blurView)
        
        blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        blurView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        blurView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: tableView.tableHeaderView!.heightAnchor).isActive = true
        blurView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width).isActive = true
        
        largeLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        smallLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        scoreLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        scoreLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: largeLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        
        smallHeaderTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        smallScoreLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        smallScoreLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: smallLabel.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
        smallScoreLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: smallLabel.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
        
        smallHeaderTitle.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.contentView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        smallHeaderTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: max(smallLabel.frame.size.height, smallScoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height)).isActive = true
        smallHeaderTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: smallLabel.frame.size.width + 5 + smallScoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width).isActive = true
        smallHeaderTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
        
        headerTitle.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        headerTitle.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: segmentedControl.topAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        headerTitle.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: largeLabel.frame.size.width + 5 + scoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.width).isActive = true
        headerTitle.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: max(largeLabel.frame.size.height, scoreLabel.intrinsicContentSize.height)).isActive = true
        
        largeLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true
        
        originalBlurRect = blurView.frame
        originalTitleRect = headerTitle.frame
        
        segmentedControl.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        segmentedControl.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
        segmentedControl.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width - 32).isActive = true
        segmentedControl.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
        segmentedControl.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 16).isActive = true

        view.bringSubviewToFront(smallHeaderTitle)
        view.bringSubviewToFront(segmentedControl)
        
        segmentedControl.layer.zPosition = 1000
    }
    
    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        view.bringSubviewToFront(blurView)
    }
    
    override func traitCollectionDidChange(_ previousTraitCollection: UITraitCollection?) {
        super.traitCollectionDidChange(previousTraitCollection)
        
        if traitCollection.userInterfaceStyle == .dark {
            (blurView.contentView.subviews[1] as! UIStackView).arrangedSubviews[1].backgroundColor = .white
            ((blurView.contentView.subviews[1] as! UIStackView).arrangedSubviews[1] as! UILabel).textColor = .black
        } else {
            (blurView.contentView.subviews[1] as! UIStackView).arrangedSubviews[1].backgroundColor = .black
            ((blurView.contentView.subviews[1] as! UIStackView).arrangedSubviews[1] as! UILabel).textColor = .white
        }
    }
}

extension TertiaryProfileScroll {
    struct HeaderGeometry {
        let width: CGFloat
        let headerHeight: CGFloat
        let elementsHeight: CGFloat
        let headerOffset: CGFloat
        let blurOffset: CGFloat
        let elementsOffset: CGFloat
        let largeTitleWeight: Double
    }
    
    func geometry(view: UIView, scrollView: UIScrollView) -> HeaderGeometry {
        let safeArea = scrollView.safeAreaInsets
        
        let minY = -(scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.safeAreaInsets.top)
        
        let hasScrolledUp = minY > 0
        
        let hasScrolledToMinHeight = -minY >= 450 - 44 - safeArea.top

        let headerHeight = hasScrolledUp ?
            (tableView.tableHeaderView as! SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView).containerView.frame.size.height + minY + 38 : (tableView.tableHeaderView as! SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView).containerView.frame.size.height + 38

        let elementsHeight = (tableView.tableHeaderView as! SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView).frame.size.height + minY

        let headerOffset: CGFloat
        let blurOffset: CGFloat
        let elementsOffset: CGFloat
        let largeTitleWeight: Double

        if hasScrolledUp {
            headerOffset = -minY
            blurOffset = -minY
            elementsOffset = -minY
            largeTitleWeight = 1
        } else if hasScrolledToMinHeight {
            headerOffset = -minY - 450 + 44 + safeArea.top
            blurOffset = -minY - 450 + 44 + safeArea.top
            elementsOffset = headerOffset / 2 - minY / 2
            largeTitleWeight = 0
        } else {
            headerOffset = 0
            blurOffset = 0
            elementsOffset = -minY / 2
            let difference = 450 - 44 - safeArea.top + minY
            largeTitleWeight = difference <= 44 + 1 ? Double(difference / (44 + 1)) : 1
        }
        
        return HeaderGeometry(width: (tableView.tableHeaderView as! SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView).frame.size.width, headerHeight: headerHeight, elementsHeight: elementsHeight, headerOffset: headerOffset, blurOffset: blurOffset, elementsOffset: elementsOffset, largeTitleWeight: largeTitleWeight)
    }
}

class SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView: UIView {
    var imageContainerHeight = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var imageContainerBottom = NSLayoutConstraint()
    
    var imageViewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var imageViewBottom = NSLayoutConstraint()
    var imageViewTop = NSLayoutConstraint()
    
    
    var containerView: UIView!
    var imageContainer: UIView!
    var imageView: UIImageView!
    
    var largeTitleOpacity = Double()
    var tinyTitleOpacity = Double()
    
    var largeLabel: UILabel!
    var tinyLabel: UILabel!
    
    var containerViewHeight = NSLayoutConstraint()
    
    var stack: UIStackView!
    
    var title: StretchyHeaderTitle!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        createViews()
        
        setViewConstraints()
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    func createViews() {
        
        // Container View
        containerView = UIView()
        self.addSubview(containerView)
        
        imageContainer = UIView()
        imageContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "d55161")
        imageContainer.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageContainer.clipsToBounds = true
        containerView.addSubview(imageContainer)
        
        // ImageView for background
        imageView = UIImageView()
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "d55161")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageContainer.addSubview(imageView)
    }
    
    func setViewConstraints() {
        // UIView Constraints
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            self.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor),
            self.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.centerXAnchor),
            self.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor)
        ])
        
        // Container View Constraints
        containerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        containerView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainer.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        containerViewHeight = containerView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.heightAnchor)
        containerViewHeight.isActive = true
        
        // ImageView Constraints
        imageContainer.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageContainerBottom = imageContainer.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.bottomAnchor)
        imageContainerBottom.isActive = true
        imageContainerHeight = imageContainer.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor)
        imageContainerHeight.isActive = true
        
        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        imageViewBottom = imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainer.bottomAnchor, constant: -50)
        imageViewBottom.isActive = true
        
        imageViewTop = imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainer.topAnchor, constant: 50)
        imageViewTop.isActive = true
        
        imageView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageContainer.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    }
    
    func scrollViewDidScroll(scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        
        containerViewHeight.constant = scrollView.contentInset.top
        let offsetY = -(scrollView.contentOffset.y + scrollView.contentInset.top)
        
        containerView.clipsToBounds = offsetY <= 0
        imageContainerBottom.constant = offsetY >= 0 ? 0 : -offsetY / 2
        imageContainerHeight.constant = max(offsetY + scrollView.contentInset.top, scrollView.contentInset.top)
        imageContainer.clipsToBounds = offsetY <= 0
        imageViewBottom.constant = (offsetY >= 0 ? 0 : -offsetY / 2) - 50
        imageViewTop.constant = (offsetY >= 0 ? 0 : -offsetY / 2) + 50
    }
}

extension UIColor {

    // MARK: - Initialization

    convenience init?(hex: String) {
        var hexSanitized = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
        hexSanitized = hexSanitized.replacingOccurrences(of: "#", with: "")

        var rgb: UInt32 = 0

        var r: CGFloat = 0.0
        var g: CGFloat = 0.0
        var b: CGFloat = 0.0
        var a: CGFloat = 1.0

        let length = String(hexSanitized).count

        guard Scanner(string: hexSanitized).scanHexInt32(&rgb) else { return nil }

        if length == 6 {
            r = CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
            g = CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
            b = CGFloat(rgb & 0x0000FF) / 255.0

        } else if length == 8 {
            r = CGFloat((rgb & 0xFF000000) >> 24) / 255.0
            g = CGFloat((rgb & 0x00FF0000) >> 16) / 255.0
            b = CGFloat((rgb & 0x0000FF00) >> 8) / 255.0
            a = CGFloat(rgb & 0x000000FF) / 255.0

        } else {
            return nil
        }

        self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
    }

    // MARK: - Computed Properties

    var toHex: String? {
        return toHex()
    }

    // MARK: - From UIColor to String

    func toHex(alpha: Bool = false) -> String? {
        guard let components = cgColor.components, components.count >= 3 else {
            return nil
        }

        let r = Float(components[0])
        let g = Float(components[1])
        let b = Float(components[2])
        var a = Float(1.0)

        if components.count >= 4 {
            a = Float(components[3])
        }

        if alpha {
            return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(r * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(b * 255), lroundf(a * 255))
        } else {
            return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(r * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(b * 255))
        }
    }

}
```

I think I gave all of the code related to my issue. If I missed something, tell me. I know that the code is really long, but I am totally clueless as to what I'm supposed to do. Any reply is welcome! I also apologize for potentially repeated code, I am posting this in a hurry.

Thank you!

Comment: There is a lot of missing code, so what you posted cannot be run as-is. However... You're adding your segmented control to: `blurView.contentView.addSubview(segmentedControl)` -- Without digging to much into your code, it's almost certain that you are changing the frame of `blurView` and/or `blurView.contentView` to the point where the segmented control is now *outside the bounds* of its superview.

Comment: @DonMag
`blurView` has the width of the screen.
`segmentedControl`'s width is the width of the screen subtracted by 32.

Comment: Where does `blurView` go when you "collapse" the stretchy header?

Comment: @DonMag it never goes away. it stays at the top, where the small title and UISegmentedControl reside. I am only offsetting it proportionally to the user's scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK - I got your code to run.

The problem is that your Segmented Control is extending *outside the bounds* of the table header view.

I think it would make much more sense to keep all of your UI elements that are part of the "stretchy header" *inside* the header class, so this is not how I would recommend doing this, but this *should* give you back your segmented control interaction:

In your `SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView` class, add this var / property:

```
weak var segControl: UISegmentedControl?
```

In `addTitle()` in your `TertiaryProfileScroll` class, add this:

```
    // your existing code
    blurView.contentView.addSubview(headerTitle)
    blurView.contentView.addSubview(smallHeaderTitle)
    blurView.contentView.addSubview(segmentedControl)
    tableView.tableHeaderView!.addSubview(blurView)

    // add this
    if let v = tableView.tableHeaderView as? SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView {
        // give our custom header view a reference to the segemented control
        v.segControl = segmentedControl
    }
```

Back in your `SecondaryStretchyTableHeaderView` class, add this func:

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    
    guard isUserInteractionEnabled,
          !isHidden,
          alpha >= 0.01,
          let sc = segControl
    else { return nil }

    // if we tap outside the bounds,
    //  but on the segmented control
    //  return the segmented control
    let convertedPoint = sc.convert(point, from: self)
    if let v = sc.hitTest(convertedPoint, with: event) {
        return v
    }
    
    guard self.point(inside: point, with: event) else { return nil }
    
    return self
    
}
```

That will allow you to interact with the segmented control, even when it is outside the bounds of the table header view.

As a side note, it appears you're setting `.layer.zPosition` where you don't need to. In `cellForRowAt` I commented out these lines:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")
    
    cell?.textLabel?.text = String(indexPath.row)
    
    //cell?.layer.zPosition = -1000
    //view.sendSubviewToBack(cell!)
    //view.bringSubviewToFront(tableView.tableHeaderView!)
    
    return cell!
}
```

and also commented out this line (at the end of `addTitle()`):

```
//segmentedControl.layer.zPosition = 1000
```

and I don't see any difference.